# Behaviour of $f'(1)$ for an analytic function $f$ from open unit disc to open unit disc satisfying $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)$ is analytic on $\Delta$, the open unit disc such that $f(0)=0,|f(z)|<1$ for all $z \in \Delta, f(z)$ is analytic at $z=1$ and $f(1)=1 .$ Then prove or disprove $|f'(1)|\geq 1$.

Here I can't deal the question with Schwarz's lemma or Schwarz Pick's lemma etc. For the functions like $f(z)=z^n, n\in \mathbb N,$ we are getting $|f'(1)|\geq 1 $.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but what about $f(z) = z/2$?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani: Note that  $f(1) = 1$.

Comment: $f(1)\neq 1$, This cannot be taken

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953279/42969.

Comment: I added an answer at the link  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/625409/the-derivative-of-a-holomorphic-function-on-the-boundary-of-the-unit-circle/3715651#3715651